# Birthday field in contacts of Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, contacts, date

I am making an application which is using birthday from contacts of device.I am testing my application on 2.2 emulator and birthday field is not present in contacts.Does any one have idea about any version of emulator which is having Birthday Field in its contacts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download device specific emulator from Motorola site. It may solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
public void getBirthdays() {

    // get data from contacts
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE};

    String selection =
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "= ? AND " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE + "=" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY;

    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
    int columnCount = cursor.getColumnCount();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
        Common.echo(cursor.getColumnName(i) + ", " + cursor.getString(i));
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```